# While Sending BNB Coin it throws error nodeError(desc: "unknown account") ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, cryptography

function which i used to send bnb

i have current user wallet address from userdefault
receiver user wallet address from textfield
amount from textfield

and i am sending that in options

function which i used to send bnb

i have current user wallet address from userdefault
receiver user wallet address from textfield
amount from textfield

and i am sending that in options

let result = try tx.send(password: "") this line throws error nodeError(desc: "unknown account") error

```
func transferETH()
{
    let strETHAmount: String = trimString(trimstr: txtTransferAmount.text!)
    let strReceiverWalletAddress: String = trimString(trimstr: txtReceiveAddress.text!)

        if strETHAmount.count == 0 {
            AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate().hideLoadingView()
            return
        }
        if strReceiverWalletAddress.count == 0 {
            AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate().hideLoadingView()
            return
        }
        
        if let myaddress = Defaults(key: DefaultsKeys.USER_DEFAULT_WALLET_ADDRESS) as? String {
            
            let walletAddress = EthereumAddress(myaddress)! // Your wallet address
            let toAddress = EthereumAddress(strReceiverWalletAddress)! // Receiver wallet address
            
            let contract = web3Obj.contract(Web3.Utils.coldWalletABI, at: toAddress, abiVersion: 2)!
            let amount = Web3.Utils.parseToBigUInt(strETHAmount, units: .eth)
            
            
            print("amount",amount!)
            
            var options = TransactionOptions.defaultOptions
            options.value = amount
          //  options.to = toAddress
            options.from = walletAddress
            options.gasPrice = .automatic
            options.gasLimit = .automatic
            let tx = contract.write(
                "fallback",
                parameters: [AnyObject](),
                extraData: Data(),
                transactionOptions: options)!
            
            print("txtxtxtxtxtx:",tx)
            
            do {
                
                let result = try tx.send(password: "")
                print("result.hash:",result.hash)
                
                AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate().hideLoadingView()
                showAlertHandlerDefaultApple(title: String.str_alert_validation_title, message: String.str_transaction_successfully_done, view: self) { action in
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                        print("yes")
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                
                
            } catch {
                AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate().hideLoadingView()
                print("**** Error :",error)
            }
        }else{
            AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate().hideLoadingView()
        }
    }
```

just say what is wrong in this

this is options data is that any thing wrong here

EthereumContract(transactionOptions: Optional(web3swift.TransactionOptions(type: Optional(Legacy),

to: Optional(web3swift.EthereumAddress(_address: "0x6378398dec8e7f3419c501919c1d2fdadcbb46fb", type: web3swift.EthereumAddress.AddressType.normal)),

from: Optional(web3swift.EthereumAddress(_address: "0xe507be01aa9c0863ab89170c632da43c21c79ad1", type: web3swift.EthereumAddress.AddressType.normal)),

chainID: nil,

gasLimit: Optional(web3swift.TransactionOptions.GasLimitPolicy.automatic),

gasPrice: Optional(web3swift.TransactionOptions.GasPricePolicy.automatic),

maxFeePerGas: Optional(web3swift.TransactionOptions.FeePerGasPolicy.automatic),

maxPriorityFeePerGas: Optional(web3swift.TransactionOptions.FeePerGasPolicy.automatic),

value: Optional(10000000000000000),

nonce: Optional(web3swift.TransactionOptions.NoncePolicy.pending),

callOnBlock: Optional(web3swift.TransactionOptions.CallingBlockPolicy.pending), accessList: nil)),

address: Optional(web3swift.EthereumAddress(_address: "0x6378398dec8e7f3419c501919c1d2fdadcbb46fb", type: web3swift.EthereumAddress.AddressType.normal)),

_abi: [web3swift.ABI.Element.fallback(web3swift.ABI.Element.Fallback(constant: false, payable: true))])

Comment: What exactly goes wrong in your code and at what line? Is it a runtime error or is the error in the response? Your question is quite unclear so make an effort and improve it.

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting this as a comment.

Comment: No of course not, then I would have posted the solution.

Comment: Joakim Danielson i added option data which i append is their anything wrong in it ?

Comment: I commented on your question in a general way because I believed it could be improved. I have no knowledge at all about the api. Sorry.